# is an annotation aware of which method it is staying and this method's current parameter list and values?

Tags: java, annotations

It is in java, and I have a method:

```
public String test(String p1, String p2){...}
```

I want to print a message like "method test was called with parameter p1=xx and p2=xx" by an annotation so that it seems like this annotation is a monitor to tell the every call details.

How can I do that by annotation, or, the same goal under the condition that no touch of the method body ?

Current I know I can write an annotation for a parameter to let me get its value. But I am not sure if the annotation for parameter is aware of its current environments, the method name or the parameter name. I want it to know.

Comment: you need to see about `AOP`. Spring already provides your requirement. You can use it :)

Comment: You're talking about aspect oriented programming. You can use AspectJ for this.

Comment: Thank you two, I will learn it.